# What's new in TeX, version 3.14159265?

Tags: tex-core, knuth

The new Knuth TeX has been released in early this month, and its version number is `3.14159265` now. It can be [downloaded here](ftp://ftp.cs.stanford.edu/pub/tex/tex14.tar.gz).

What's new in this release?

And a further-more question, where can one find the change log of TeX (itself), and will D.E.K. himself summarize the change(s) somewhere?

Comment: There were also some minor documentation changes.

Comment: I believe Stack Exchange (ergo Tex) is not an news site. People wondering what a new version brings should read the changelog.

Comment: @Braiam While that is true, remember that (1) each site has a bit different policies of various stuff, (2) this is much more subtle and specific than asking "what is new in `C++11`", (3) this information is significantly harder to find than for other stuff, where the "wiki-idea" of StackExchange can come to play. This is not about a specific package inside *TeX, this is about **the TeX**!

Comment: @tohecz I find more useful teach the user how to catch the fish, so maybe a question about "How I find the change made in the TeX?" would be more productive and relevant, no?

Comment: @Braiam However, only useful to him, only for 5 minutes. This question is useful to many. The new version of TeX is its 9th version in it's more-than-40-year-long existence. It's not something that happens every day and that would get outdated soon, giving people need to have a similar but different question next week. Very likely the next change in TeX core will be not sooner than in 5 years, and again, it will likely be a minor change like this one. I'd suggest you to settle down here, I'm sure that in some time you'll find out that this question is just fine, and actually very good!

Comment: @tohecz ok, I will check this out.

Comment: @Braiam Yes indeed, telling one to catch the fish is better than just giving him/her a fish. However, I would modify the question later. Thank you! `:)`

Comment: I don't know what is new, but from the `texbook.log` I see that D.E.K. uses `TeX Live 2009/Debian`. Good to know.

Comment: I believe it can print out beautiful Pi documents...!?

Comment: Just saw that wikipedia didn't contain the latest version. I tried to find a good reference I could cite apart from the tarball, but it seems apart from this page and the tarball there are practically no relevant pages for this release.

Comment: Related CTAN update http://www.mail-archive.com/ctan-ann@dante.de/msg06082.html

Answer (score 73, accepted):

There have been two bug fixes, one in TeX and one in Metafont. If you look into the tarball, you find a subdirectory called `errata`. In it you find

```
tex82.bug
mf84.bug
errorlog.tex
```

In the last file there's a resumé of the changes, in the first two you can find the actual corrections.<sup>1</sup>

The bug fix in TeX is related to the control sequence with empty name.

> 428​. \endcsname\csname should be followed by space in print_cs, just as all
>   other multiletter control sequences are (found by Oleg Bulatov, 14 Sep 2008)
>
> @x module 262
>         begin print_esc("csname"); print_esc("endcsname");
>   @y
>         begin print_esc("csname"); print_esc("endcsname"); print_char(" ");
>   @z

If one runs the (admittedly bizarre) TeX file

```
\endlinechar=-1
% define the empty control sequence
\def\
{foo}
% define another macro
\def\baz{\
text}
% show \baz
\show\baz
```

the output on the terminal is

```
> \baz=macro:
->\csname\endcsnametext .
l.9 \show\baz
```

while, with the bug fix, it will be

```
> \baz=macro:
->\csname\endcsname text.
l.9 \show\baz
```

as it should. The result of `\show` applied to the empty control sequence is always represented as `\csname\endcsname`: the bug produces invalid output, as it can be clearly seen.

The bug fix in Metafont is related to a memory leak:

> 572​. Memory leak in make_ellipse on symmetric pens that don't have
>   a point on the x-axis (Eberhard Mattes, 03 June 2008)
>   @x module 536
>   done1: link(p):=s; beta:=-y_coord(h);
>   @y
>   done1: if (link(p)<>null) then free_node(link(p),knot_node_size);
>   link(p):=s; beta:=-y_coord(h);
>   @z

Congratulations to Oleg Bulatov and Eberhard Mattes (the creator of emTeX, by the way) for having being awarded the check from DEK.

---

By the way, there is a bug in the bug list: in the first above reported line it should be

```
\csname\endcsname
```

and not

```
\endcsname\csname
```

Is this worthy a check? `;-)`

---

#### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> [An article by Knuth in TUGboat](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb35-1/tb109knut.pdf) was published after I wrote this answer.

Comment: Hi egreg. Do you know where I can download the latesat version of `plain.tex` from Knuth's homepage? I can't find it (which I've been abel to before).

Comment: @SvendTveskæg In the tarball you find `plain.tex` in the `lib` subdirectory. There has been no change to it. Only `manmac.tex` has been slightly modified.

Comment: okay, @egreg, i'll forward that report to dek; it's up to him to decide whether it's worth a check.  his summary of changes will be published in the next issue of tugboat.

Comment: Wow. D.K. fixed a but now which has been found in 2008?! He's really, really fast.

Comment: @glglgl The last batch of bug fixes was carried out in 2007. Considering that the bug can manifest itself only in very obscure settings, there was no hurry. In the past there have been urgent fixes besides the planned maintenance.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for your answer. But, since I modified my question, for the suggestion from Braiam, will you update your current answer? In my view, only a few changes have to be made. `:)`

Comment: Looking at a diff of the `tex.web` files, I notice a couple more differences: in one place "in case hanging indentation or \.{\\parshape} are in use" has been fixed from "…is in use", and three more modules have been added to the index entry for "inner loop". Of course these are changes only to documentation. :-)

Comment: For future reference, might also be worth linking to [The TeX tuneup of 2014](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb35-1/tb109knut.pdf), published in TUGboat, Volume 35 (2014), No. 1.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Thanks, I added the link as a footnote to my answer.

Answer (score 37):

In the file `./errata/TeX82.bug`, you will find what you want:

```
428. \endcsname\csname should be followed by space in print_cs, just as all
other multiletter control sequences are (found by Oleg Bulatov, 14 Sep 2008)

@x module 262
      begin print_esc("csname"); print_esc("endcsname");
@y
      begin print_esc("csname"); print_esc("endcsname"); print_char(" ");
@z
```

I don't think this is something that could be called 'new (feature)', however, our TeX has just stepped further to the version `pi`. Oh, if you've read the message just below, you may not like this 'bad news'. `:(`

```
999. The absolutely final change (to be made after my death)
@x module 2
@d banner=='This is TeX, Version 3.14159265' {printed when \TeX\ starts}
@y
@d banner=='This is TeX, Version $\pi$' {printed when \TeX\ starts}
@z
When this change is made, the corresponding line should be changed in
Volume B, and also on page 23 of The TeXbook.
My last will and testament for TeX is that no further changes be made
under any circumstances. Improved systems should not be called simply `TeX';
that name, unqualified, should refer only to the program for which I have
taken personal responsibility.  -- Don Knuth
```

Comment: the "bad news" has been there since at least the early 1980s.  the request that the exact name "TeX" be used only for knuth's original version has been honored by everyone so far who has created any extensions.  in fact, latex these days is based on pdftex, not on the canonical "TeX"; however, all extensions of which i am aware have also tried to make sure that a version of the extended program will pass knuth's "trip" test, to ensure that the program as documented in the texbook remains valid.

Comment: Thank you Ch'en Meng, but I think the answer from egreg is better, since he/she provides more explanation about the very change. Vote up for your information.