# Missing space after "ø" \o

Tags: spacing, accents, characters, font-encodings

I am writing a German text with some Scandinavian names which include characters like ø. In one case the ø is at the end of the word and the following whitespace is ignored.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Near the town of Errits\o is Fredericia. 

\end{document}
```

appears as

[image]

The word separation between "Erritsø" and "is" is missing. What is causing this problem and how can I solve it? (How) Is it affected by inputenc and/or fontenc?

Comment: Use `Near the town of Errits\o{} is Fredericia`. Spaces are gobbled after control sequences by default.

Comment: See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173678/which-commands-consisting-of-a-non-letter-eat-spaces-afterwards/173679#173679

Comment: AFAIK the space marks the end of the command `\o`. Otherwise the system has no way to recognize where the end of a command is. That's also why it is gobbled and vanishes. Otherwise you would have difficulties writing words with an `\o` in the middle.

Comment: Makes sense. I tried a second space... Thanks, and sorry for the dupe - I couldn´t find anything since I didn´t know what to look for.

Comment: If you have access to the letter ø on your keyboard and use an appropriate input encoding, then just type the letter directly without using macros. Also remember to use a suitable font encoding.