# Can someone explain what is labxx in the source code of tex

Tags: tex-core, sourcecode, web

[image]

As shown above, I saw many labXXX in the source code of tex and pdftex. I'm really confused about them and there is no comments at all. Is there any doc that demonstrate the meaning of every labXXX?
Thanks!

Comment: The source code shown in the screenshot you posted does *not* look like TeX of LaTeX code. What makes you think that it's TeX or LaTeX code?

Comment: These are labels (targets to jump to with `goto`). Using `goto` in the program flow is a programming style that has been discouraged long ago, but is nevertheless the actual model of the underlying machine (the processor). For this reason, you often find it in autogenerated code (from a transpiler), which I assume to be the case here. AFAIK, `tex` was developed in a Pascal dialect called WEB, which is nowadays transformed to C before getting compiled to machine code. The code you have been looking at may be the intermediate of this process.

Comment: @Mico look at the filename not the code:-)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about C code, not TeX/LaTeX/etc., and the question being asked is a generic C question that has no specific relevance to any TeX variant. A version of it might be on topic at [so].

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question as this question about the TeX source code is specific to the unique way in which the TeX program is written and compiled (written in WEB and translated to Pascal and then C) — these labels are auto-generated by this translation process (by either `tangle` or `web2c`) and would *not* be on-topic on a generic C question site like Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DavidZ how can the source code of Tex  be off topic?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Let me counter with a question: suppose I took the same screenshot and asked "What does `goto` mean?" Would that also be on topic here?

Comment: @DavidZ well possibly, in particular if you asked that in a C forum you'd probably just get told not to use goto:-)  as ShreevatsaR commented the fact that this is C is sort of irrelevant here, the idiom is an artefact of the web2c system and web2c counts as one of the "tex and friends" collection of programs that are on topic here. The basic fact is that the tex source spurns most notions of structured programming and is a vast collection of gotos and global variables, the screenshot just shows one instance of that in the compile process as it passes from web to C to executable code.

Comment: @DavidZ or to put it another way, on stackoverflow you would not get the answer that there are no comments because the comments have been removed and you can see typeset version of them by looking at tex.pdf.

Comment: Ah well, forget about `goto` then - what if someone had asked "what does `if` mean?" When I voted to close, I viewed this question as kind of on the same level as that. But it seems that there is something TeX-specific about that code, so in light of the comments I withdraw my claim that the question should be closed.

Comment: @DavidZ In case it wasn't clear, the question wasn't asking something like “what are labels / what does goto mean”, but was asking something like “how come this source code uses meaningless labels like `lab22` — is the meaning of each label documented anywhere”, so it's specific to the TeX source code. Anyway, doesn't matter now, glad it's reopened now. :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Indeed that's not clear from the question. The OP hasn't given any indication that I can see that they know what a label is, and thus it seems far more natural to me that they're asking what a label is than that they're asking why those particular labels appear in the source code. Do you have some extra information from the OP that tells you that's what they meant? If that is true, then IMO it's a far more compelling justification to keep the question open than what was said in the previous comments - but as I mentioned, I don't see anything in the question to suggest that.

Answer (score 17):

The file you are looking at is not really "source code" it is `tex0.c` which is C derived (by web2c) from the `tex.web` source code of TeX, which is written in web (documented pascal).
Almost all comments are dropped in this conversion.

So what you see are various jumps to a procedure arbitrarily labelled as `lab22`

If you look in tex.web you will see the procedure

```
@p procedure clear_for_error_prompt;
begin while (state<>token_list)and terminal_input and@|
  (input_ptr>0)and(loc>limit) do end_file_reading;
print_ln; clear_terminal;
end;
```

and various places this is referenced eg

```
@ @<Get user's advice...@>=
loop@+begin continue: clear_for_error_prompt; prompt_input("? ");
```

In the generated C this sends up as

```
void 
clearforerrorprompt ( void ) 
{
  clearforerrorprompt_regmem 
  while ( ( curinput .statefield != 0 ) && ( curinput .namefield == 0 ) && ( 
  inputptr > 0 ) && ( curinput .locfield > curinput .limitfield ) ) 
  endfilereading () ;
  println () ;
}
```

and a labeled reference to it

```
    lab22: clearforerrorprompt () ;
```

and then some jumps to that point from other parts of the loop:

```
    goto lab22 ;
```

To understand the source it is best to read the tex typeset document that can be generated from tex.web not the C that is extracted from it.

`texdoc tex`

in texlive will bring up a hyperlinked typeset version of this source. This section appears as:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

*(Just to add a bit more detail to the other answer…)*

Short version of answer: For the labels specifically shown in the screenshot in the question, you can read the label `lab22` as `continue`, the label to which the code will `goto` to resume a loop, and read label `lab20` as `restart`, the label to which the program will `goto` to start a procedure again. (See §15 of the TeX program, or below.)

---

Long version:

### Why does the TeX program have so many `goto`s?

#### The goto debate

Once upon a time, computers were programmed in machine language or (a slight improvement) in assembly language, where control flow is expressed using branches / jumps. Donald Knuth (who would go on to write TeX) did a lot of such programming (examples: 1957–1960 ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9JOrmgHw28), [texts](https://www.computerhistory.org/collections/search/?s=X8738.2019)), [1960](http://ed-thelen.org/comp-hist/B5000-AlgolRWaychoff.html#7)). As higher-level programming languages evolved, they used a keyword like `goto` for such arbitrary jumps, and also introduced control-flow structures for common kinds of jumps like conditionals (`if`)  and loops (`while`). Then in 1968, a major controversy was ignited when an article by Edsger Dijkstra (submitted as "A Case Against the Goto Statement") was published by the CACM editor Niklaus Wirth as a letter under the title “Go To Statement Considered Harmful”. Roughly the two camps of the debate were:

1. The `goto` statement is not necessary and is better avoided; the control-flow structures provided by the high-level languages are enough.
2. The existing control-flow structures are too limited; sometimes `goto` is indeed necessary / good.

The former position was represented by “structured programming” (Dijkstra, Wirth, Hoare, etc). Knuth, though he wrote an encyclopedic article in 1974 summarizing both (and more) sides ([PDF](https://www.cs.sjsu.edu/%7Emak/CS185C/KnuthStructuredProgrammingGoTo.pdf), [HTML](http://www.kohala.com/start/papers.others/knuth.dec74.html)) always had his sympathies towards the latter.

For what it's worth, the current state of the debate (see [summary on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Goto&oldid=964186650#Criticism)) seems to be that while the *title* of the letter seems to have become dogma and almost every programmer avoids or [is afraid of using](https://xkcd.com/292/) the *word* “goto”, in practice the control-flow structures available at the time (of [ALGOL 60](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ALGOL_60&oldid=963495846), [ALGOL W](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ALGOL_W&oldid=956108766), [ALGOL 68](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ALGOL_68&oldid=963352561) etc) were indeed deemed insufficient, and languages have indeed gained more control-flow structures that Dijkstra wouldn't have liked and which cover the examples raised in (say) Knuth's paper: early `return` from functions, and in loops `continue` and `break` (even labeled ones, in languages like Java and Rust).

#### `goto` in Pascal

Knuth wrote the first version of TeX (meant for use only at Stanford) in [SAIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=SAIL_(programming_language)&oldid=918565017), but when there was enough interest in the program elsewhere and the danger of incompatible implementations, he set out to rewrite the program in a (then) widely available language in a maximally portable way, and the [natural choice](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb26-1/beebe.pdf#page=10) was Pascal. Now [Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pascal_(programming_language)&oldid=967276840) (invented by Wirth mentioned above) tries to strongly encourage structured programming:

- Functions don't have `return` statements; instead you have to assign to a pseudo-variable with the same name as the function and control flow has to exit by reaching the bottom of the function.
- There is no `break` or `continue` in loops; you can use booleans (or use `goto`).
- `goto` is still available but discouraged, e.g. labels have to be declared beforehand at the top of the function (or program), and these labels have to be numbers: no symbolic names are allowed!

So for example, where in modern languages you can write a function like this (sum of all the odd numbers less than n):

```py
def sum_odd(n):
  if n < 1: return 0
  sum = 0
  for i in range(n):
    if i % 2 != 1: continue
    sum += i
  return sum
```

(just a made-up example with `return` and `continue`; of course this function can be written without them) in Pascal if you wanted an exact translation, you would have to use `goto`s and pick some ad-hoc numeric labels:

```pascal
function sumodd(n: integer)
label
  42, 100;
var
  i, sum: integer;
begin
  if n < 1 then 
  begin
    sumodd := 0;
    goto 100
  end
  sum := 0;
  for i := 1 to n - 1 do
  begin
    if i mod 2 <> 1 then goto 42;
    sum := sum + i;
  42:
  end
  sumodd := sum;
100:
end
```

which I guess is sufficient inducement to avoid `goto`s and rewrite using booleans etc (straightforward in this case, but not always).

### `goto` in TeX and WEB

These features of Pascal were fine for a teaching language, but Knuth (like [others](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/bwk-on-pascal.html)) must have found it annoying for writing large software programs with real-world constraints of performance etc., so he created a system called WEB that works around a lot of these limitations. The same program above in WEB could be written as:

- in some earlier section, `define` symbolic names and macros for the whole program:

  ```
  define exit = 10
  define continue = 22
  define return == goto exit
  ```
- then when writing your function, you can use the above names (e.g. remember to put a label called `exit` before the end of the function), for a *slightly* better experience.

This is the system followed by TeX, which uses `goto` but usually adhering to certain conventions, described in [Section 15 of the program](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/tex/tex.pdf#page=8):

[image: Section/module 15 of the TeX program]

If you were using the Pascal implementation of TeX directly you would see numeric labels in the source code generated by `tangle` (part of WEB), but in practice most TeX users use a distribution (like TeX Live) that is based on converting this WEB/Pascal to C (using a system like `web2c`), in which the numeric labels are once again translated to start with `lab`.

### Common labels

#### lab20 = restart

This is used for example here ([§380](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/tex/tex.pdf#page=146), I've reformatted the indentation):

```pascal
procedure get_x_token; {sets |cur_cmd|, |cur_chr|, |cur_tok|, and expands macros}
label
    restart, done;
begin
    restart:
    get_next;
    if cur_cmd <= max_command then
        goto done;
    if cur_cmd >= call then
        if cur_cmd < end_template then
            macro_call
        else
        begin
           cur_cs := frozen_endv;
           cur_cmd:=endv;
           goto done; {|cur_chr=null_list|}
        end
    else expand;
    goto restart;
    done:
    if cur_cs = 0 then
        cur_tok := (cur_cmd * 256) + cur_chr
    else
        cur_tok := cs_token_flag + cur_cs;
end;
```

so this structure of the function body being `restart: ... if (...) goto done; ... goto restart; done: ...` is basically an infinite loop, exited by `goto done` when some condition is hit.

#### lab22 = continue

This is used to re-do loops, for example things like

```
while true do 
begin 
  continue:
  ...
  if ... then goto continue;
  ...
end
```

or variants thereof (putting `continue` at the end of the loop body, etc).

### The specific example in the question

An added source of confusion is that what we're running (if using a modern distribution like TeX Live) is not TeX-as-written-by-Knuth directly, but one to which several changes/patches have been applied — and these changes may not always follow the same conventions for the labels, and sometimes aren't even valid Pascal/WEB (e.g. not declaring labels), as they've only been tested via the web2c pipeline (translated to C and run through a C compiler), not via a Pascal compiler. The one in the question shows things that come from EncTeX (see [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/enctex?lang=en), [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/MLTeX%20EncTeX%20and%20SyncTeX%20TeX%20extensions#EncTeX)). In the source code, what looks like [this](https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/blob/05b95467a0001b7fa7474dbbbae7669a2c51b751/texk/web2c/enctex.ch#L879-L903):

```pascal
...
  if (i = start) and (not mubyte_start) then
  begin
    mubyte_keep := 0;
    if (end_line_char >= 0) and (end_line_char < 256) then
      if mubyte_read [end_line_char] <> null then
      begin
        mubyte_start := true; mubyte_skip := -1;
        p := mubyte_read [end_line_char];
        goto continue;
      end;
  end;
restart:
  mubyte_start := false;
  if (mubyte_read [buffer[i]] = null) or (mubyte_keep > 0) then
  begin
    if mubyte_keep > 0 then decr (mubyte_keep);
    return ;
  end;
  p := mubyte_read [buffer[i]];
continue:
  if type (p) >= 64 then
  begin
    last_type := type (p) - 64;
    p := link (p);
    mubyte_token := info (p); last_found := mubyte_skip;
  end
...
```

gets turned into the (almost unreadable) C code you showed in the question:

```c
...
  if ( ( *i == curinput .startfield ) && ( ! mubytestart ) )
  {
    mubytekeep = 0 ;
    if ( ( eqtb [27215 ].cint >= 0 ) && ( eqtb [27215 ].cint < 256 ) ) {

      if ( mubyteread [eqtb [27215 ].cint ]!= -268435455L )
      {
        mubytestart = true ;
        mubyteskip = -1 ;
        p = mubyteread [eqtb [27215 ].cint ];
        goto lab22 ;
      }
    }
  }
  lab20: mubytestart = false ;
  if ( ( mubyteread [buffer [*i ]]== -268435455L ) || ( mubytekeep > 0 ) )
  {
    if ( mubytekeep > 0 )
    decr ( mubytekeep ) ;
    return Result ;
  }
  p = mubyteread [buffer [*i ]];
  lab22: if ( mem [p ].hh.b0 >= 64 )
  {
    lasttype = mem [p ].hh.b0 - 64 ;
    p = mem [p ].hh .v.RH ;
    mubytetoken = mem [p ].hh .v.LH ;
    lastfound = mubyteskip ;
  }
...
```

My suggestion, if you're looking at the source code for either understanding or debugging (or rather, finding bugs), would be to start with either LuaTeX (written in C, though manually translated from WEB first: e.g. `get_x_token` is [here](https://github.com/TeX-Live/luatex/blob/0018e91cab886fbca31feed340e3b18dd97b0181/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/tex/expand.c#L484-L509)) or one of the other [non-WEB reimplementations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507846/are-there-any-non-web-re-implementation-of-tex-core-in-recent-years) — they may not have all the extra features from TeX Live, but they should be easier to work with.